# Vue js + Rails 6 - Unknown custom element: <list>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker

I have fresh Rails 6 app with Vue.js

app/javascript/app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <p>I am App component</p>
    <list></list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import list from './list.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: function () {
    return {
      message: "Hello Vue!"
    }
  },
  components: {
    list
  }
}

<style scoped>
p {
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

And app/javascript/list.vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    I am List Component
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'list',
  data: function () {
    return {
      posts: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And app/javascript/packs/hello_vue.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount()
  document.body.appendChild(app.$el)

  console.log(app)
})
```

But in browser I get error

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:638 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <list> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <App> at app/javascript/app.vue
       <Root>
```

Why list component not found ? I imported it successfully and have name for it.

Comment: I suggest putting `console.log(list)` on the line immediately after where you `import` it in `app.vue`. That will confirm that it is being imported correctly as well as confirming that you're running the latest version of `app.vue`.

Comment: @skirtle thanks a lot , you save my life!!! After console log, I investigated that I forgot closed <script> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @skirtle suggested, I added console.log and found that  tag was unclosed